# Retrieve value from html 'value' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor, session-variables

How can I retrieve the the actually value defined within the html element attribute named 'value'?

Before a user signs up, I am setting a session variable with a value that shall be either 'publisher' or 'reader' depending on which div they click on. This session value will be used upon user creation.

```
<template name="authJoinType">
<div class="container join-type">
    <div class="row"> 

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <a href="{{pathFor route = 'join'}}">
            <div class="join-type-inner" id="userTypeSelect" value="reader">Reader</div>
        </a>
        </div> 

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <a href="{{pathFor route = 'join'}}">
            <div class="join-type-inner" id="userTypeSelect" value="publisher">Publisher</div>
        </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

client.js (Trying to set the session variable to either 'reader' or 'publisher' depending which div out of the two they click on)

```
Template.authJoinType.events({
'click div.join-type-inner': function(e, tmpl) {
    var userType = $(e.target).find('#userTypeSelect').val();
    Session.set('userType', userType);
    var selectedUserType = Session.get('userType');
    console.log(selectedUserType); // this is printing out 'undefined'
}
});
```

Help? Am I targeting the incorrect div to begin with?

Comment: use class as `userTypeSelect` instead of id because id should be unique then change `.find('#userTypeSelect').val();` to this `.find('.userTypeSelect').html();`

Comment: You can't have two or more elements with `id="userTypeSelect"`, that's not a valid HTML.

Comment: @Atul I do not want to grab the html "Reader" or "Publisher", I want the value to be embedded within an element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
var userType = $(e.target).find('#userTypeSelect').val();
```

To:

```
var userType = $(e.target).attr("value");
```

Comment: Yes sir! This works right out of the box. I will remove the two identical ids, as it's incorrect practice and unnecessary for my code anyway. Thank you sanki

Answer (score 0):

You must use unique `id`s for each element in HTML but you have used `id="userTypeSelect"` for multiple elements, so change it.

You can use `.attr('value')` to read value attribute of div. here `.val()` will not work as `div` don't have value as such but though you can have attribute with  name `value`.

And modify your script as shown below

```
Template.authJoinType.events({
'click div.join-type-inner': function(e, tmpl) {
    //use 'this' reference to read value attribute,
    //here 'this' is the clicked element
    var userType = $(this).attr('value');
    Session.set('userType', userType);
    var selectedUserType = Session.get('userType');
    console.log(selectedUserType); // this is printing out 'undefined'
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

- You have duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid and will cause issues in your JS - as you've discovered.
- The `value` attribute is not valid for `div` elements. You can instead use a `data-*` attribute to store custom data in an element.
- `div` elements cannot be placed inside an inline `a` element, change them to `span`.
- Given that the click event you define is on the `.join-type-inner` element you don't need to perform the `find()` as `e.target` is the element you need.

Try this:

```
<template name="authJoinType">
    <div class="container join-type">
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <a href="{{pathFor route = 'join'}}">
                    <span class="join-type-inner" data-value="reader">Reader</span>
                </a>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <a href="{{pathFor route = 'join'}}">
                    <span class="join-type-inner" data-value="publisher">Publisher</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
Template.authJoinType.events({
    'click div.join-type-inner': function(e, tmpl) {
        var userType = $(e.target).data('value');
        Session.set('userType', userType);
        var selectedUserType = Session.get('userType');
        console.log(selectedUserType); // should say 'reader' || 'publisher' depending on clicked link
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight however, the click event is not yet printing out the value into the console and the span messes up the bootstrap grid layout.

Comment: It seems the value attribute is being retrieved within the div element. I removed the duplicate ids and implemented sanki's change.

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone referencing the post. The resulting working answer looks like this. Please vote for sanki for this answer. I'm just re-laying the info.

html:

```
<template name="authJoinType">
<div class="container join-type">
<div class="row"> 

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <a href="{{pathFor route = 'join'}}">
        <div class="join-type-inner" value="reader">Reader</div>
    </a>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <a href="{{pathFor route = 'join'}}">
        <div class="join-type-inner" value="publisher">Publisher</div>
    </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

client.js

```
Template.authJoinType.events({
'click div.join-type-inner': function(e, tmpl) {
    var userType = $(e.target).attr("value");
    Session.set('userType', userType);
    var selectedUserType = Session.get('userType');
    console.log(selectedUserType);
}
});
```