# Meteor: inserting a session variable value into a field upon user creation

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-accounts

This is branching from my previous question sent earlier [Retrieve value from html 'value' attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269234/retrieve-value-from-html-value-attribute). I am now trying to insert a session variable value into field named 'userType' upon user creation. I have kept the insecure package so I can immediately perform  Meteor.users.find().count(); in the console. So far, the users are not being created.

Am I inserting the session variable value the correct way,  should this session value be inserted server side with Accounts.onCreateUser?

The client js

```
Template.joinForm.events({
'submit .form-join': function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var firstName = t.find('#firstName').value,
    lastName = t.find('#email').value,
    email = t.find('#email').value,
    password = t.find('#password').value,
    username = firstName + '.' + lastName,
    profile = {
            name: firstName + ' ' + lastName,
            userType: selectedUserType
};

    Accounts.createUser({
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        profile: profile
    }, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            alert(error);
        } else {
            Router.go('/');
        }
    });
}
});
```

I have made the 'userType' session variable global, please see as follows...

```
Template.authJoinType.events({
'click div.join-type-inner': function(e, tmpl) {
    userType = $(e.target).attr("value");
    Session.set('userType', userType);
    selectedUserType = Session.get('userType');
    console.log(selectedUserType);
}
});
```

Comment: Are you storing the value in the Session because it is on a different route? Ultimitlily I am wondering why you don't just grab the value on new user creation. i.e userType = $(".field").val();

Comment: Yes it on a different route. The user decides what userType they are by clicking on a particular box. I will bring the user creation to the same route but this value is unknown until the user clicks anyway. So it must be stored either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[createUser](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser) takes an options object with at most four fields: `username`, `email`, `password`, and `profile`. You are passing a fifth field which is being ignored. In order to transmit the `userType` data to the server you will need to add it to the `profile` object in the call to `createUser`.

---

If it's important that `userType` exist on the root of the user document (instead of in the profile), you can modify it in the [onCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) callback like this:

### client

```js
profile = {
  name: firstName + ' ' + lastName,
  userType: userType
};
```

### server

```js
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  if (options.profile) {
    if (options.profile.userType) {
      user.userType = options.profile.userType;
      delete options.profile.userType;
    }
    user.profile = options.profile;
  }

  return user;
});

Meteor.publish(null, function() {
  // automatically publish the userType for the connected user
  // no subscription is necessary
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {userType: 1}});
});
```

Comment: This was vital to fixing my code (createUser explanation). The userType field now gets created in the profile. Now that I wish to move the field, the server code needs a little fix please. There is error thrown.

Comment: this deletes the userType located within profile, so thats great so far. However, it is not created in the root user document.

Comment: The code is correct. If you run `meteor mongo` you can see it in the shell. You will not see the extra fields on the client without [publishing them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151879/publish-certain-information-for-meteor-users-and-more-information-for-meteor-use). Again this is a good case for just putting the data in your profile so you don't have to do that step.

Comment: Hi David, are you familiar with iron_router? My publication is correct but the user is not being subscribed to "userData"> Please check my code above that I have added. According to the docs, I have created a global hook for each path so each path should be subscribed to "userData"

Comment: Btw, the code has successfully worked I check the mongo shell. Thanks for asserting the valid code.

Comment: I updated the answer with a publish that doesn't need a subscription. Give that a try - it may be easier than modifying your router.